# How did dnegs guess cannon's hand

Tags: poker-strategy

I was watching a poker tournament video [here](https://youtu.be/5LxYQgN7O3M)

Hand of interest starts at 6:53 in the video. At 9:03, during showdown, Negreanu guesses correctly that cannon has four jacks.

How did he figure four jacks instead of another, more common better hand, say a set of jacks? What did i miss?

Comment: most of us miss things Daniel sees

Comment: Daniel has a very good ability to read people, he is or was highly regarded for this. However I will say this as well, it's a TV show, they select the entertaining hands. He very well may have read hands wrong and just it not made the cut. I will also say these are people playing with money they likely will never have a chance to win again, most of these people are amateurs who the money means a lot to them. They're less likely to reach the river without a very strong hand, and even less likely to call an all-in without an extremely strong hand.